# Power Conditioners and Laser Printers

Tags: printer

Is it safe to plug a laser printer into a power conditioner?  In this case, it is a Brother HL-2170W plugged into a Panamax M5400-EX.

Answer (score 1):

If you do use it, you need to use the high powered ports on bank 5.  But you'd need to check to make sure your printer doesn't exceed the 15A rating on the power conditioner.  From the looks of the docs, 15A is the max for the whole unit, so keep this in mind.  (I am not an expert on this stuff, but that is just waht I see first hand).  Is there a reason why you want to power condition power for a laser printer?  A simple surge supressor isn't sufficient?

Comment: It's more of a physical limitation.  I have a limited number of outlets in which to plug things into.  Currently, the line conditioner is plugged into one of two wall outlets (the other outlet is taken up by equipment from Verizon).  I can rewire things so that the surge supressor plugs into the wall and then the laser printer and power conditioner plug into the surge supressor.

Comment: In my opinion, I would plug the printer into a power strip along with the line conditioner.  Laser printers can be pretty big power hogs. Also, unless the VeriZon equipment needs to be plugged in directly to power (like for a powerline ethernet adapter) odds are, it would benefit from the line conditioner as well.  So that would free up that power for the laser printer.  Again, I am not an expert, just my humble opinion.